# Where is the places.sqlite database on linux?

Tags: c, firefox

Where can I found the `places.sqlite` file database on Ubuntu/Linux 10.4, Firefox 5.0 (X11)?
I want read the open urls on firefox using C. But I not found the file. I tried following [these instructions](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Mozilla_Firefox_3_History_File_Format), but the `.mozilla` dir does not exists in `/home/<user>/` folder.

Comment: Closers - can explain please? it's programming question,I believe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
find / -name 'places.sqlite'
```

In my system the answer was:

```
/home/edu/.mozilla/firefox/qk8lh1kf.default/places.sqlite
```